# MotionEvent or DragEvent? For this implementation Android

Tags: graphics, android

For this implementation, should I be using a MotionEvent or DragEvent for moving the ball in the meter? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a MotionEvent you read its history. So you need to wait for the gesture to complete before you can manipulate the ball.

DragEvent input can be handled directly.

Comment: Based on this example (http://myandroidwidgets.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/DragDrop/src/com/beanie/example/Home.java) it looks like my awnser was wrong. You can use MotionEvent, the difference between the 2 is now unkown to me.

Comment: But with DragEvent, we will have to hold or press for a period right...what do u suggest? I think that it wont make it very user friendly...

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you want your application to work.  I would venture to guess that for a DragEvent, you would need to hold down a longer click on the ball to enter into a DragEvent.  Where a MotionEvent would be picked up as soon as you touch the screen and move your finger.

It is really all about the user experience you want for your users.

Comment: I am expecting to create an effect similar to the seek bar in android.....the same response effect...wat do you suggest??

Comment: The seekbar would be responding to TouchEvents.  If I were to be doing it, I would resond to TouchEvents.

Comment: I am really having some trouble trying to implement this..Could someone tell me whats the best way to go about this?

Comment: You should ask a new question, specifying what the issue is that you are having.  Also, if you consider this question answered, you should think about accepting a 'correct' answer.